# Simple Darboux Integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let  $f(x) = \begin{cases} -1 &\mbox{if } x \leq 0 \\ 
> 1 & \mbox{if } x> 0 \end{cases} $
>   
>  find the integral of $f$ in $[-1,1]$

So first we divide $[-1,1]$ into $2n$ equal parts so for all parts in [-1,0], $m_i=-1$ and for [0,1] $M_i=1$ 
How did they got to those series, and how did the calculate them? 

$\underline s(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)*\frac{1}{n}+(-1)*\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{i=n+2}^{2n}1*\frac{1}{n}=-\frac{2}{n}$

$\overline s(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)*\frac{1}{n}+1*\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{i=n+2}^{2n}1*\frac{1}{n}=0$

Comment: $m_i$ should be equal to $M_i$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I have edited it

Answer (score 2):

See the following picture:

[image]

The interval is divided into $2n$ parts as in the picture. I believe $\underline s(f,P)$ is the left hand sum. So in each subinterval, you pick the left boundary point. Using the $y$ value at that point as the height of the little rectangle (I shaded the first one). You can see from $1$ to $n$, we have $(-1)\frac{1}{n}$. At $n+1$, the function is still defined as $-1$, which is the middle term. Starting from $n+2$, the $y$ values are $1$. So the area of the rectangles are $1\cdot \frac{1}{n}$.

Now to calculate the sum, notice that the terms in the sum has nothing to do with the index $i$, so you have factor them all out, for example, for the first term:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)*\frac{1}{n}=(-1)*\frac{1}{n}\cdot n=-1$$

The other terms can be calculated the same way and the right hand sum is similarly done.